# What library for c# to use for the graphs of a Roundness-meter software?

Tags: c#, charts

I'm working on a metrology laboratory and i need to develop a software in c# for a roundness-meter equipment, I've already started and I've found a problem, I need the software to show real-time graphics from the measurement that is being made, for that I'll need to use a library like Mscharts or Zedgraph, that is really fast for refreshing the information and has support for round graphs like Polar or radar, especially polar charts.
The problem I've seen in most libraries is that they all lack support for round graphs and are relatively slow.
Does anyone has a sugestion of a lybrary I could use?

Thank you for your help.
PS:The Software should show graphics like these ones:
[image]

[image]
[image: The final software should be like this one]

Comment: I think what you're looking for is an algorithm.  The software you need seems to be already available from ABTech, Inc.

Comment: Real time with a garbage collected language is impossible. Perhaps you are just searching for something really fast? AND: If it should be exactly like that software, why is that software not the solution?

Comment: You should estimate the roundness, right? And then plot some graphic, right? What is the format of the data which you should estimate in the first place?

Comment: ok,the software I need is similar in the graph part, but the rest is compleatly different, I've already got the algorithms for calculating all the points, the problem is that the graphics need to be refreshed as the equipment moves and gets a new measurement, that requires a good performance, for instance, they are like 50 new groups of points(array of floats) per second, and if I have to render the polar decorations for every update on the image, it will be very time consuming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would render them with GDI(+) (in winforms app).

Yes that is basic line drawing, but it will be powerful enough for the examples you gave. You need to refresh your highschool mathematics, but it will give you lots of control over the output and it will be fast.

Comment: But it gives you no estimation of the roundness of the plotted graphic.

Comment: @Mare: Where in the question is this asked?

Comment: perhaps the title is misleading

Comment: ^^' sorry if the title is misleading, what i asked was some library(like zedgraph for exmaple..) that would have polar support to allow me to create those kind of graphics as fast as possible =s srry for the confusion

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this will help or not.  [Xceed Charts](http://xceed.com/Chart_WinForms_Intro.html) in their advanced section talks about doing polar charts.  Unfortunately they did not provide any images so you should talk to their sales people and see if you can get an eval copy to evaluate.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using the roguewave IMSL Numerical .NET library

[homepage of the IMSL numerical .NET library](http://www.roguewave.com/products/imsl-numerical-libraries/.net-library.aspx)

[Examples of graph, resembling what you have posted above](http://www.roguewave.com/Portals/0/products/imsl-numerical-libraries/net-library/docs/5.0.1/chartpg/polar.html)

Especially the Polar plot seems to be what you need here.

Comment: this could be my solution, do you have any idea of around how much it costs? i'm not finding that information on their homepage

Comment: @WillKraemer - you need to make an account and request a quote. Look at the "get started" menu on the right.

Comment: I'm sorry, I do not know the prices they have.

Answer (score 1):

I was surprised that ZedGraph doesn't support polar graphs out-of-the-box and there are very few examples online. Using [this guildline](https://sourceforge.net/p/zedgraph/discussion/392231/thread/d74e10c5/), I created my own polar graph with ZedGraph in C#. I hope that WillKraemer has solved his problem already (4 years passed) and someone else finds my implementation useful.

First is the ZedGraphControl initialization:

```
        myZg = new ZedGraphControl();
        GraphPane myPane = myZg.GraphPane;

        // Init lists
        RadarPointList dseries1 = new RadarPointList();
        RadarPointList dseries2 = new RadarPointList();

        // Maximize available space in pane
        myPane.Legend.Position = LegendPos.InsideTopLeft;
        myPane.Title.IsVisible = false;
        myPane.XAxis.IsVisible = false;
        myPane.YAxis.IsVisible = false;
        myPane.Border.IsVisible = false;
        myPane.Chart.Border.IsVisible = false;
        myPane.Margin.All = 0;

        // Create concentric grid with 30 degrees spacing & add corresponding labels
        for (double i = 0; i < 36; i+=3.0)
        {
            TextObj gridlbs = new TextObj((i * 10.0).ToString("0°"), (radius + 10.0) * Math.Cos((i * 10.0 * Math.PI) / 180.0), (radius + 10.0) * Math.Sin((i * 10.0 * Math.PI) / 180.0));
            gridlbs.FontSpec.Border.IsVisible = false;
            LineObj gridlns = new LineObj(0, 0, radius * Math.Cos((i * 10.0 * Math.PI) / 180.0), radius * Math.Sin((i * 10.0 * Math.PI) / 180.0));

            myPane.GraphObjList.Add(gridlbs);
            myPane.GraphObjList.Add(gridlns);
        }

        // Draw circular grid, 5 should look okay
        for (double i = (radius / 5.0); i <= radius; i += (radius / 5.0))
        {
            EllipseObj gridcrl = new EllipseObj(-i, i, 2.0 * i, 2.0 * i);
            gridcrl.ZOrder = ZOrder.E_BehindCurves;
            myPane.GraphObjList.Add(gridcrl);
        }

        // Make sure the pane is big enough to fit the labels around the polar plot
        myPane.XAxis.Scale.Min = -(radius + 20.0);
        myPane.XAxis.Scale.Max = (radius + 20.0);
        myPane.YAxis.Scale.Min = -(radius + 20.0);
        myPane.YAxis.Scale.Max = (radius + 20.0);

        _selectedRadius = radius;
        // Keep X & Y axis in the correct ratio to avoid distorting polar circle 
        myZg_Resize((object)"Startup", EventArgs.Empty);
        myZg.Resize += new EventHandler(myZg_Resize);
        myZg.ZoomEvent  += new ZedGraphControl.ZoomEventHandler(myZg_ZoomEvent2);

        // Draw snailly curves (example)
        for (int i = 0; i < 360; i++)
        {
            double r = (double)i/360.0 * radius;
            PointPair pt = new PointPair(PointPair.Missing, r, null);
            dseries1.Add(pt);
            PointPair pt2 = new PointPair(PointPair.Missing, radius - r, null);
            dseries2.Add(pt2);
        }

        // Curves are somple LineItem
        FirstCurve = myPane.AddCurve("Snail", dseries1, Color.Blue, SymbolType.None);
        SecondCurve = myPane.AddCurve("antiSnail", dseries2, Color.Red, SymbolType.None);

        // Rotate the lists to aling with labels
        dseries1.Rotation = 0;
        dseries2.Rotation = 0;
```

I had to make sure that the graph is not distorted when the form/control resizes, so I added this in the Resize Event:

```
    protected void myZg_Resize(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        GraphPane pane = myZg.GraphPane;
        myZg.AxisChange();
        bool IsXMin = ( pane.Rect.Width < pane.Rect.Height ) ? true : false;
        if (IsXMin)
        {   
            // Scale based on X (width)
            pane.XAxis.Scale.Max = (radius + 20.0); pane.XAxis.Scale.Min = -(radius + 20.0);
            double xPixPerUnit = (double)pane.Chart.Rect.Width / (pane.XAxis.Scale.Max - pane.XAxis.Scale.Min);
            pane.YAxis.Scale.Max = (double)pane.Chart.Rect.Height / xPixPerUnit / 2.0;
            pane.YAxis.Scale.Min = -pane.YAxis.Scale.Max;
            myZg.AxisChange();
        }
        else
        {
            // Scale based on Y (height)
            pane.YAxis.Scale.Max = (radius + 20.0); pane.YAxis.Scale.Min = -(radius + 20.0);
            double yPixPerUnit = (double)pane.Chart.Rect.Height / (pane.YAxis.Scale.Max - pane.YAxis.Scale.Min);
            pane.XAxis.Scale.Max = (double)pane.Chart.Rect.Width / yPixPerUnit / 2.0;
            pane.XAxis.Scale.Min = -pane.XAxis.Scale.Max;
            myZg.AxisChange();
        }
    }
```

Also, I decided to block the user from any zooming actions:

```
    protected void myZg_ZoomEvent2(ZedGraphControl sender, ZoomState oldState, ZoomState newState)
    {
        myZg_Resize("zoomevent", EventArgs.Empty);
    }
```

The output looks like the picture below:

[image]

Suggestions always welcome!